# ASP.NET Core not binding arguments from body after upgrade to 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json-serialization

I just upgraded an ASP.NET Core project from 2.2 to 3.1 and now my model binding doesn't work for POST requets. I read that the default JSON serializer changed from Newtonsoft.JSON to System.Text.Json in .NET Core 3. Could this be the reason?

My action and class look like this

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Foo([FromBody]Bar req)
```

```
public class Bar
{
    public string Fiz;
    public int Buzz;
}
```

Comment: If you suspect it is JSON serializer, you could install Newtonsoft JSON back https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/

Comment: Do I need to do anything to make the ASP framework use this other JSON serialized?

Comment: Yes, you will need to install the nuget package and add it like `services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();`, check [this](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/12/19/using-newtonsoft-json-in-net-core-3-projects/) out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The reason for this error is the new JSON library.

For some reason `System.Text.Json` does not populate fields, it only populates properties. So you need to change your class definition `Bar` to use properties

```
public class Bar
{
    public string Fiz { get; set; }
    public int Buzz { get; set; }
}
```

The serialization process uses the setter, so you cannot omit those.

Comment: Luckily this fix can be done without changing anything else in the code, as the syntax to get and set fields and properties are the same.

Answer (score 5):

I just want to note that if modifying your models was not an option for you, then you can add JSON.NET Support back.

Simply install the following nuget package :

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
```

Then in your startup.cs, where you add MVC, do :

```
services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

And then you are back to using JSON.NET which was the serializer used for .NET Core 2.X projects.

https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/12/19/using-newtonsoft-json-in-net-core-3-projects/